# Rename multiple records oracle

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, oracle11g, sql-update

I am trying to rename multiple records in a column that contains special characters

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(Name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]') ;
```

I've tried to fetch every single record that contains a special character into an array and loop through it with the update statement.
But....when i try to change the first record , the other ones(3) also change to the new value.
I try to set the new value with an INPUT field/box , is there also a possibilty to change the line above the textbox  to the old value(te name with the special characters)

```
  CREATE TABLE LOCATION
   (    "ID" NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
        "NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) ;
Insert into SYSTEM.LOCATION (ID,NAME) values ('2','RE#$');
Insert into SYSTEM.LOCATION (ID,NAME) values ('3','rete%#');
Insert into SYSTEM.LOCATION (ID,NAME) values ('4','Testjue');
Insert into SYSTEM.LOCATION (ID,NAME) values ('5','Test#');
```

/

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR name_cursor IS
    SELECT id, name
    FROM Location
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]')
    FOR UPDATE OF name;
BEGIN
  FOR loc_rec IN name_cursor LOOP
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(loc_rec.name);
    UPDATE Location SET name = '&whatever' WHERE Location.id=loc_rec.ID;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

This changes all values in the table with special characters to the input of the prompt "whatever", but i need to set the value different for each record.
Here a picture what happens when the input was "test"
[image]

Comment: Can't you just do a direct update, without using a cursor? `UPDATE Location SET name = '&v_location' WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]');`. As for having multiple rows update for one statement, probably they have the same value for `name`.

Comment: I got like 3 names, tes#%t, $tac% ,&verflow  and i want them changed in the correct way, tes#%t must become test , $tac% must become stack and so on. Soo i want to loop thouh the selected items and change them indiviual

Comment: Do you mean three names that have the identical value? If that's the case, and if you want to process them one at a time with a cursor you'll have to identify the rows some other way, for example by a primary key. If that's what you want to do, please post the table structure and I may be able to help.

Comment: The table structure is just : id - name. Id is primary

Comment: I notice that your sample code has SYSTEM.LOCATION.  Please do not use the SYSTEM schema for building your own objects, as it is very bad practice.  SYS and SYSTEM are the schemas reserved by Oracle for building the database and administering its internals.  Altering those schemas can break your database and invalidate any support contract you have.  That may not be relevant to you right now but it's helpful to cultivate good habits from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to figure out the logic for transforming names like tes#%t, $tac% ,&verflow into test, stack, overflow, etc. As for updating and reporting one line at a time, something like this should work:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR name_cursor IS
    SELECT id, name
    FROM Location
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]')
    FOR UPDATE OF name;
BEGIN
  FOR loc_rec IN name_cursor LOOP
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(loc_rec.name);
    UPDATE Location SET name = 'whatever' WHERE CURRENT OF loc_rec;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

It's important to select the `id` so the cursor knows what the current row is for the `WHERE CURRENT OF` in the update command.

This doesn't use the bulk fetch so it may run a bit slower (at least on paper), but it's more compact. If the bulk fetch is important to you, I'd recommend going with your original code, incorporating the `id` column into the cursor, and using `id` instead of `name` in the `WHERE` clause of your `UPDATE` command.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response, but i am getting errors at the moment
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist (Syntax error on "OF")

And an other question: is it posible to see/show the old  value first, so you can decide how you want to update that record?

Comment: sorry wrong error code:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 58:
PLS-00413: identifier in CURRENT OF clause is not a cursor name
ORA-06550: line 10, column 58:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 10, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Comment: I've tried to change the statement a bit:

UPDATE Location SET name = 'whatever' WHERE location.id=loc_rec.id;

but when i run it, i changes all 3 records to whatever instead of 1 record

Comment: I don't get any errors when I try this. If you have `WHERE CURRENT OF loc_rec`, the cursor name has to be `loc_rec`. Are you doing this as an anonymous block (starting with `DECLARE`) or as a procedure (starting with `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE abc`)?

Comment: If you're using `WHERE location.id = loc_rec.id` and `id` is a primary key, I don't know of any way you could have three rows updated. If you're still having trouble could you post your code?

Comment: See my edit, i;ve posted an create script and a screenshot of the output when i ran the script

Comment: You're getting `test` as the new value because `&whatever` is set to `test`. It's not a case of a single `UPDATE` hitting three rows here; it's hitting them one at a time (as it steps through each row of the cursor) and setting the same value. So the logic of stepping through the rows is solid; the problem is that you can't use a substitution value like `&whatever` to set a different value for each row. That's logic that you'll need to figure out. If you have trouble with it I'd suggest posting it as a new question because it'll get more attention.

Comment: Also note that, if you use `WHERE Location.id=loc_rec.ID` in your update, you don't need the `FOR UPDATE OF...` at the end of the cursor definition - that's only needed when you do `WHERE CURRENT OF...`.

Comment: Use `...WHERE CURRENT OF name_cursor`. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your code as

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR name_cursor IS
    SELECT id, name
    FROM Location
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]')
    FOR UPDATE OF name;
BEGIN
  FOR loc_rec IN name_cursor LOOP
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(loc_rec.name);
    UPDATE Location
      SET name = CASE LOC_REC.ID
                   WHEN '4' THEN 'Testjue'
                   ELSE 'Test'
                 END
      WHERE Location.id=loc_rec.ID;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

> "I got like 3 names, tes#%t, $tac% ,&verflow and i want them changed
>   in the correct way, tes#%t must become test , $tac% must become stack
>   and so on."

You've got two different rules there: the first rule turns `%` into `null`, the second turns `%` into `k`.  That's a problem and you need to resolve it.

Once you have decided which rule you actually want to implement you can use a simple TRANSLATE call to change the unwanted characters.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions216.htm#SQLRF06145).

So, to remove them:

```
UPDATE Location 
    SET name = translate (name
        , 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|'
        , 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890'
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '([!@#\$%\^&\*=\+/<>\?\|]+)')
/
```

... or to change them:

```
UPDATE Location 
    SET name = translate (name
                 , '!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|'
                 , 'la3sk6787abciqi'
                         )
   WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '([!@#\$%\^&\*=\+/<>\?\|]+)') 
/
```

Here's [the SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29a46/17).

Answer (score 0):

I've created something to keep it kinda simple
 First i'll select every single record with special characters, and show the ID and NAME. Now i've got the ID and Name i can use them in my cursor
Example:
I've got an record where ID "2" got special characters:

```
        ID NAME               
---------- --------------------
         2 RE#$                 
         3 rete%#
```

So when the inputfield "ID"pops up i'll type in "2", now i'll get an prompt for the "Name" where i will type the new name.
 So this is my new script:

```
SELECT *
FROM LOCATION
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]');
/
DECLARE
  CURSOR name_cursor IS
    SELECT id, name
    FROM Location
    WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(name, '[!@#$%^&*=+/<>?|]')
    FOR UPDATE OF name;
    v_RecordID number;
BEGIN
  v_RecordID := &ID;
  FOR loc_rec IN name_cursor LOOP
    DBMS_Output.Put_Line(loc_rec.name);
        UPDATE Location SET name = '&Name'
        WHERE Location.id=v_RecordID;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Is there still a way to improve it? Mabye with parameters or something?